# changing Color of square on button press

Tags: javascript, html

How do I change the color of this square without having to manually change it. On a button press.
Here is the code:
Html:

```
<tr   <td>
<style>
  .square {    <td>
<style>
  .square {   background: #000000;
          height: 100px;
           width: 100px;
             }
           </style>
             <div class='square' id="squareColor" onclick="colorChoose()"> 
             </div></td>
               </tr>
```

js:

```
 function colorChoose() {
 var colors = 
  ["blue","red","green","yellow","orange","cyan","purple","teal", "brown"
  ];
       var chooser = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
     document.getElementById("squareColor").style.backgroundColor == 
       chooser;
          }
```

Comment: If not a button click, what should trigger the color change?

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` is comparison. Change the following code to a single equals sign:    `document.getElementById("squareColor").style.backgroundColor == chooser;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in this code: `document.getElementById("squareColor").style.backgroundColor == chooser;`

What you want to do is `document.getElementById("squareColor").style.backgroundColor = chooser`;

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:

```js
const square = document.querySelector(".square");
const colors = ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "orange", "cyan", "purple", "teal", "brown"];

square.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const chooser = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = chooser;
})
```

```html
<div class="square" id="color"></div>
```